# Any one ever heard of the term collapsed Backbone?

Tags: networking

Any one ever heard of the term collapsed Backbone?  Could it be a virtual network that could be referred also to this term.

Comment: Have you googled it? The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collapsed_backbone) gives a short description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes they are referring to a virtual network.

> A non distributed backbone where all network segments are interconnected via a single internetworking device. A collapsed backbone may be a virtual network segment existing in a device such as a repeater, router, or bridge.

http://bitwisertraining.com/Glossary/CollapsedBB.htm